# Is $|\sin x|$ a Lipschitz function?

Tags: continuity, lipschitz-functions

I would like to know how can I prove that the function:
\begin{equation}
f(x)=|\sin x|, \quad x\in \mathbb{R}
\end{equation}
is (or isn't) Lipschitz continuous.

I studied an example of the funtion $f(x)=|x|^{1/2}$ which is not a Lipschitz function on any interval containing zero, but the problem is that I do not know how to proceed with this one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the cosine is bounded by $1$, by the mean value theorem, $|\sin x - \sin y| \le |x - y|$ for all $x,y \in \Bbb R$. Therefore, since $||a| - |b|| \le |a - b|$ for all $a,b\in \Bbb R$, we have

$$|f(x) - f(y)| \le |\sin x - \sin y| \le |x - y|$$

for all $x,y\in \Bbb R$. Hence, $f$ is Lipschitz continuous.

Comment: I see. But why do you use the boundness of cosine and not sine? That has to be clear for me. Thank you!

Comment: @Mitscaype by the mean value theorem, given $x, y\in \Bbb R$, $\sin x - \sin y = (\cos c)(x - y)$ for some $c$ in between $x$ and $y$. So $|\sin x - \sin y| = |\cos c||x - y| \le |x - y|$.

Comment: Totally correct, I just managed to show it all by myself. Thank you again!

Comment: I see you showed that $\sin$ is Lipschitz, but the OP asked for $|\sin|$... Please correct using the $1$-Lipschitzness of $|\cdot|$.

Comment: @Robert I showed that $|f(x) - f(y)| \le |x - y|$ for all $x,y\in \Bbb R$.

Comment: Sorry, misread, could you edit your question so that I could un-downvote ?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to see this is to note that $|x|$ is a Lipschitz function as well as $\sin x$ (because the modulus of its derivative, i.e, $|\cos x|$ is bounded by $1$). Compositions of Lipschitz functions are Lipschitz.